# HQL left join where left is null

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hql

how to write this query on HQL:

```
select pp.* 
from Part pp
 left join Product p on pp.ProductID = p.ID
where p.ID is null
```

i need parts without products. Part has property Product (many-to-one)

I tried

```
from Part p 
where p.Product is null
```

but it generate invalid query.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resolved with:

```
from Part p 
where not exists (from Product pr where p.Product = pr)
```

**Update**:
and this exactly as on SQL!

```
from Part p 
   left join p.Product as pr
where pr is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from Part p
where p.Product.Id is null
```

should work
Although your query should also work. What is the generated query that you're getting?